# How to implement camshift or mean shift for hand tracking in C# with EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

I'm on my way to build program for control mouse pointer with hand recognition and tracking. I'm finished with my hand tracking use skin color segmentation. Now, I'm gonna tracking this hand and I choose **camshift** algorithm. But I'm a little bit confused how to implement camshift to my target (hand) use **emgucv** and **c#**.

Or can you give me recomendation what algorithm better to this kind of case? Such **mean shift** or any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a code for camshift algorithm in OpenCV already.

> ../OpenCV-2.4.5/samples/cpp/camshiftdemo.cpp

You need to port this code and maybe some functions to C#.